# react-native-awesome-gallery shows only one image without gesture possible

Tags: react-native

related to : https://github.com/Flair-Dev/react-native-awesome-gallery

I tried many things, but nothing is working.
I made the gesture and reanimation installation as wanted.

what I have :

```
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import Gallery from 'react-native-awesome-gallery';
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const ModalInfos = (props) => {    
    const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false)
    return (
        <View style={style.centeredView}>
            <View style={style.modalView}>
                <Text>{props.infos.name}</Text>
                <Text> lots of infos here</Text>
                ....
                ....
                ....
                <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>  check menu </Text>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => setShowMenu(true)}
                >
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons name="book-open-variant" size={20} color={'#fff'} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

            {
                showMenu &&
                <View style={style.gallery}>
                    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                        <Gallery
                            data={["http://10.0.2.2:8080/images/menu/" + props.infos.barInfos.photomenu1, "http://10.0.2.2:8080/images/menu/" + props.infos.barInfos.photomenu2]}
                            onIndexChange={(newIndex) => {
                                console.log(newIndex);
                            }}
                        />
                    </GestureHandlerRootView>
                </View>
            }
        </View>
    )
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
    centeredView: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        marginTop: 22,

    },
    modalView: {
        width: '95%',
        margin: 20,
        backgroundColor: "white",
        borderRadius: 20,
        padding: 35,
        alignItems: "center",
        shadowColor: "#000",
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: 2
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.25,
        shadowRadius: 4,
        elevation: 5
    },
    gallery: {
        flex: 1,
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        position: 'absolute',
        zIndex: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#202124e6',
    }
});

export default ModalInfos;
```

With or without the `GestureHandlerRootView`its the same result, i can see only the first image, and I can't do anything, no swipe, no zoom, not gesture.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to `react-native-image-viewing`
works more than perfectly